# Why do we wear a tallit at kol nidre?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, tallit-gadol, evening-night, kol-nidre

Why do we wear a tallit at kol nidre?

And if one arrives late to kol nidre and night has fallen already, should he put one on?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your timely and relevant question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: No source available, just from memory - I am fairly sure that the problem is only with the _brachah_ which must not be said after sunset (not nightfall) because the time for tzitzit is when they can be seen (i.e. not a night). If someone is delayed to the extent that it is after sunset, then they should put on the tallit _without_ a brachah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summarizing from  [p. 349 of this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=oTan4XIKqfYC&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=tallit+on+night+of+yom+kippur&source=bl&ots=QXQG-Jj8Ig&sig=XXLoGyoBxD_cfF0Y3ZiAJLWIs3M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rXwtVL-EGseryASNx4LQDw&ved=0CGMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=tallit%20on%20night%20of%20yom%20kippur&f=false):

The custom originated from Rav Meir of Rothenberg who stated that on the night of Yom Kippur we recite the 13 "middot" - Attrubutes of Mercy, multiple times during our tefillah (after the Amidah). There is a midrash (mentioned in Talmud Rosh Hashannah 17b) that G-d wrapped himself in a tallit, similar to a Chazzan when he taught Moses these attributes. Therefore, we imitate what G-d did when we recite them.

My curiosity - we can apply this "argument" to the recital of selichot, esp. the 1st one which is said at night. There, too, we recite the 13 middot multiple times, yet we do not wear a tallit, then. Perhaps, Yom Kippur is special?

Answer (score 8):

[Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Yom Hakipurim page 181 note 24](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46445&st=&pgnum=177) in the name of Siach Yitzchak that we wear a Talis at Kol Nidrei based on the Yerushalmi Chagiga 1:5 that says that one needs to wear a Talis at the time of Hataras Nedarim.

He goes on to say that one should only make a Bracha on the Talis up to the time he would normally Daven Mincha.

Comment: +1. Would you happen to be able to explain the connection (written about in that footnote in נטעי גבריאל) between "נדרים flying away, therefore you should wear a Talis"?

Comment: The Yerushalmi is 1:8

Comment: @Sam: You can fix the answer.

Comment: See the Korban Haeida and Pnei Moshe and here for Rav Chaim Kanievsky's biur http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47658&st=&pgnum=26&hilite=

Comment: The Nitei Gavriel just sourced the Mishna which appears in the Bavili as well his main point was the Gemara on the Mishna which discusses being meutaf in a tallis during hataras nedarim and various opinions about it

Comment: The flying in air reference is that it does not have an explicit. Source rather a halacha lMoshe Misinai